# In Html5 Video tag, Play button shows very big

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DysTB.png)

This is a mobile screenshot of this style output.

I'm not assign any css to video tag still play button it's not comming normal size in **mobile device**.

I've tryied below css code.

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
video::-webkit-media-controls-pause-button {
    max-width: 3rem !important;
    max-height: 3rem !important;
}
```

still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

**The Differ between browsers and devices, determine the size of the play button in the video tag. However, CSS allows you to replace the default styles.Most browsers should be able to use the CSS code you provided, however certain mobile devices might not. To change the play button's size, use the following**

***CSS code:***

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background-size: contain;**
}
```

This malware primarily targets the play button on WebKit browsers, which are widely used on mobile devices and include Safari and Chrome. The play button's size is determined by its width and height, and its proportionate scaling is ensured by the background-size parameter.

If the default styles aren't being overridden by the styles you apply, consider adding the!important declaration:

***Css Code:***

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
  width: 3em !important;
  height: 3em !important;
  background-size: contain !important;
}
```

If none of these fixes work, it's conceivable that a plugin or another CSS rule in your code is overriding the styles. In this situation, you might need to target the play button with a more precise CSS selector or look into where the competing styles are coming from.

Comment: Do you mean malware?